# Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting this error when running my spring boot application. It is a CRUD API that I am trying to connect to my table data in SQL developer. I would really appreciate some help.

Application Properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:DIP:@localhost:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username = DIP
spring.datasource.password = DIP
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
server.port = 8080
```

Code That Generated Exception

```
    private EmployeeDAO dao;
@BeforeEach
void setUp() throws Exception {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:DIP:@localhost:1521:orcl");
    dataSource.setUsername("DIP");
    dataSource.setPassword("DIP");
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    dao = new EmployeeDAO(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
}
```

Oracle Driver System Path Pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/ojdbc8.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection URL looks odd to me.

The part of the connection URL after `jdbc:oracle:` specifies which type of Oracle JDBC driver to use, as there's more than one of them.  The only possible values this can take are `thin`, `oci` (or `oci8`?) and `kprb` (according to the [Oracle JDBC driver documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-C4F2CA86-0F68-400C-95DA-30171C9FB8F0)).  In your code, you've set this to `DIP`, which appears to also be the username you are using.

I've never had any need to use `kprb` (in fact I didn't even know about it until today), and I haven't used `oci` in years.  `thin` is the type of driver I use most often and would be the type of driver I would recommend you try to use.

Try replacing `DIP` in your connection URL with `thin`, i.e. `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl`.

Note that this URL appears twice in your code, once in your properties file and once in what appears to be a test class.  You will presumably need to change it in both.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm as soon as I replaced 'DIP' with 'thin'.